# setInterval() acts weird after switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, effects

I have created an effect using javascript to show top categories in my project.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, it works perfectly fine. But after running for sometime; If the user leaves this page and switched to another tab and come back to this after sometime, then it starts to act weird.

[image]

Below is the code which I'm using to make this effect.

```
var curCat = 0;
var cats = [
  "<a href='/search/?cat=1'>Animals</a>",
  "<a href='/search/?cat=2'>Graffiti</a>",
  "<a href='/search/?cat=3'>Figures</a>",
  "<a href='/search/?cat=6'>Landscape</a>",
  "<a href='/search/?cat=7'>Portrait</a>",
  "<a href='/search/?cat=9'>Other</a>"
];

function catSlider() {
  $(catDisplay).html(cats[curCat]);
  $(catDisplay).fadeIn();
  setInterval(function() {
    $(catDisplay).fadeOut();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (++curCat >= cats.length) {
        curCat = 0;
      }
      $(catDisplay).html(cats[curCat]);
      $(catDisplay).fadeIn();
    }, 400);
  }, 3000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  catSlider();
});
```

What is causing this problem? What am I missing?

Comment: It's because you have a timeout in the interval.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I need the timeout to keep the gap between 2 displayed items

Comment: timeout + interval = why?

Comment: The inner setTimeout should be a callback to the `.fadeOut()`.  Or add `.finish()` before `.fadeIn()`

Comment: @epascarello - Makes sense to me. Every three seconds, fade out and then fade in after 0.4 seconds; rinse, repeat. Would be fine if it weren't for throttles.

Comment: The 400 on the timeout matches the default animation time for `fadeOut()` - so it's fadeOut, when finished, set value and fade back in - which is what the callback to fadeOut is for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder An you know how how intervals and timers work in the browser...

Comment: @epascarello - Mostly. :-) I meant "on the surface" it makes sense conceptually. It just runs afoul the reality of timer scheduling on browsers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timers get throttled back when the tab doesn't have focus (and many other odd games, such as being accelerated when focus returns), so your `setInterval` and your `setTimeout` may get out of sync.

Instead, just use `setTimeout`, where each action (fade out and fade in) triggers the next:

```
function catSlider() {
  $(catDisplay).html(cats[curCat]);
  $(catDisplay).fadeIn();
  function fadeOut() {
    $(catDisplay).fadeOut();
    setTimeout(fadeIn, 400);
  }
  function fadeIn() {
    if (++curCat >= cats.length) {
      curCat = 0;
    }
    $(catDisplay).html(cats[curCat]);
    $(catDisplay).fadeIn();
    setTimeout(fadeOut, 3000);
  }
  setTimeout(fadeOut, 3000);
}
```

And/or you might consider the callbacks that `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` can trigger, in particular on the `fadeOut`:

```
function catSlider() {
  $(catDisplay).html(cats[curCat]);
  $(catDisplay).fadeIn();
  function fadeOut() {
    $(catDisplay).fadeOut(fadeIn);  // ***
  }
  function fadeIn() {
    if (++curCat >= cats.length) {
      curCat = 0;
    }
    $(catDisplay).html(cats[curCat]);
    $(catDisplay).fadeIn();
    setTimeout(fadeOut, 3000);
  }
  setTimeout(fadeOut, 3000);
}
```

---

Side note: If you like, you can replace

```
if (++curCat >= cats.length) {
  curCat = 0;
}
```

with

```
curCat = (curCat + 1) % cats.length;
```

Comment: Many thanks. Never knew there's a throttle back issue.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala - Browsers only really started doing it significantly in the last few years. :-) I think there was one that completely suspended timers before that, but not the complex behavior they have now.

Answer (score 0):

The 3000ms interval might run faster than a 400ms timeout as the browser tries to get the interval in sync after you get back to the tab. To resolve this, you could use a delayed loop, e.g.:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

 (async function() {
    while(true) {
      hideCurrent();
      await timer(400);
      showNext();
      await timer(2600);
   }
 })()
```